# What alternative syntax exist for C/C++? (think SPECS or Mirah)

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, syntax, code-generation

I wondered if there are any simpler or more powerful syntax for C or C++. I have already come across [SPECS](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/ModestProposal.html). That is an alternative syntax for C++. But are there any others and what about C?

It could also be a sort of code generator so that things like functors could be defined less verbosely. I imagine it could be made as a code generator that compiles to C or C++ code which is very similar to the code you wrote in the alternative syntax.

[Mirah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirah_%28programming_language%29) is an example of doing this for Java.

Ideally I would want to write C in Go like syntax. I like how they fixed switch-case, and in general made everything much less verbose.

Comment: In the compiled language world, this doesn't really make much sense; all you need is a language with binding support for C/C++ runtime systems. (Note that a MSVC C++ code won't run on Linux directly anyway; it's the runtime that matters.) Thus, in that light, FORTRAN is an "alternative syntax", or Modula II, or anything you can compile to objects linkable to the desired runtime.

Comment: This is not true. A lot of complexity and power from C++ comes from the templates which is an compile-time language.

Comment: Just from the link you posted, I see that they claim to have a `switch` statement without fall through and on the other end to have the same semantics. That doesn't go together.

Comment: According to the link you provided, Mirah is a completely separate language that compiles to the same JVM as Java, not an alternate syntax for Java.

Comment: I landed on this page looking for syntax like Scala or Python, for fully powered C++. Unfortunately SPECS doesn't begin answering that at all, and I fear that the completely changed declaration syntax will scare away too many people. The key to making a programming language successful is to use as similar syntax to other languages as possible while still changing the most annoying parts (i.e. see Python that is still essentially based on C syntax despite a few major changes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only general-purpose tool that I'm aware of is [Lazy C++](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/), which lets you create a single `.lzz` source file from which it can generate the `.h` and `.cpp` files.

There are also numerous approaches to doing code generation for C++.  (For examples, see [Cog](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/), [Pump](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/PumpManual.md), or [Wikipedia's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_code_generation_tools).)  These aren't full-fledged alternate syntaxes, but they can help with particular categories of syntax (such as automatically generating templates taking 1 to N arguments, to work around the lack of variadic templates).

Answer (score 13):

```
#define BEGIN {
#define END }
```

No! **Just say NO!**

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a change in syntax, consider a change in abstraction: Increase your abstraction with a custom-defined DSL. Tool support would be necessary to reach optimal productivity.

If your goal is simplification, a lightweight modeling approach, either text-based (like [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)), graph-based (like [MetaEdit+](http://www.metacase.com)) or tree-based (like [AtomWeaver](http://www.atomweaver.com)) would remove some complexity on the project by simplifying the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only a syntax you're after, why can't you define your own, as a trivial preprocessor->parser->C-pretty-printer chain? It will be no more than a semantically reach preprocessor, something of a CamlP4 style, but for C. No one but you knows what kind of syntax you'd find suitable, so its implementation is entirely up to you.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but I am not sure what the best tools for doing something like that is.

Comment: @Adam Smith, any parsing toolchain will be ok - e.g., Antlr with a Java backend, or (much better) any functional language with ADTs (SML, OCaml, Haskell, ...).

Comment: It is a huge effort to define a custom syntax that will suit C++ development (do I need to mention that the mere parsing of C++ is extremely painful and only a few teams in the world have managed to do that entirely?). Having a custom language with wider user group would allow it to be better and have a selection of IDEs and other tools to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look to me like SPECS is really C++ anymore, I certainly would have a hard time reading such code (at least initially).

You should pick a language based on your needs, not pick a specific language and then modify it to fit what you want to do.

If you want to program Go, then program in Go, don't try to write C in a Go-like syntax as that'll just make it hard for anyone who actually knows C to read your code.

Comment: Picking a language an modifying it to your needs is a decent way of implementing a new language. Also, languages with equal semantics, with only differences in syntax are equal. Syntax is too unimportant in comparison to the other parts of the language.

Comment: In a corporate environment you can seldom use whatever language you want. Besides for integration with existing libraries etc one might prefer something that compiles to C or C++. I want to be able to write low level code and interface tightly with C, so regular Go is not and option. But I can live without the garbage collection and goroutines.